# Caller Activity gets onStop() callback when resulatant activity gets crash

Tags: android, android-activity

Currently my application flow is like

• few activity leads to activity A

• Activity A leads to activity B by calling startActivityForResult()

• Activity B leads to activity C (Activity from other application with all permissions) by
calling startActivityForResult()

Now when activity C gets crash I am not able to see activity B, it directly leads me to the activity A.

following are some callbacks I am getting in activity B after activity C crashes

– onStop()

– onDestroy()

which indicates activity B is getting finish/Kill/destroy.

but I am not finishing activity B.

I want some flow to do when activity C crashes.

Any help?, Thanks in advance for the responses.

Note: This crash is intentional created to test and handle such scenario in activity B.

**Edit 1:**

To start Activity C I use following code snippet

```
public onButtonClick(){
   Intent myIntent = new Intent();
   int requestCode;
               myIntent.setClassName(OTHER_APPLICATION_PACKAGE_NAME,OTHER_APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_NAME);

startActivityForResult(posLeadListActivityIntent, requestCode);

}

onActivityResult(){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG,"in onActivityResult");
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
             parseAndHandleResult(requestCode,data);
          }
}
```

Comment: please add some relevant part of code and error stacktrace, otherwise nobody can help....

Comment: Can you suggest what kind of code snippet will help?

Comment: post your activity code @jimit & post your error log from android monitor.

Comment: @SaravanaRaja  will this works? please let me know for other code particular code snippet if needed.